# Should good comments be merged into the answer post or be left as comments?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

This is probably more of a SE usage question, but if the answer has a comment on it that is really good, like a link proving the answer is correct.  Should we edit the answer to include that link, or just leave the link in the comments as is?

referring to this question btw
[Where does the word ダイヤ come from that means "train schedule"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1213/where-does-the-word-come-from-that-means-train-schedule)

Answer (score 5):

I would say if the comment adds good and useful information, merge that into the answer (and provide attribution to the commentator).  Answers are more visible and lasting than comments.  Furthermore, someone might have more information about information in a comment (or even a complaint that the comment is incorrect) and you can't downvote or edit comments.

I think we should start discouraging looking at the comments for complete answers and just put all of the answers in answers, at least when a significant part of the answer is actually in the comments.

Comment: Agreed. Comments are there to offer commentary *about* the post. By all means, if the text of the actual answer can be improved with that input, then do so. That's the purpose of the wiki aspect of Stack Exchange; to go back, edit, and improve the answer. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/about

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, I do not think that it matters.  The comment is plainly visible as it is now.  (A link to Wikipedia is hardly a *proof* of a statement, but this is a separate issue.)

But if there are many comments, it is sometimes useful if someone (the commenter, the answerer, the asker or anyone else) summarizes the most important comments.

Answer (score 2):

If the comment is truly good, then it would (should?) be upvoted, which keeps it above the comment fold and easily accessible. So I think the system already provides something like what you're looking for.